SwiftUI Alert not displaying properly in a MacOS menu Bar App
I am developing a simple menu bar app on mac. It has a window containing a button saying "do something", of course, to simulate a network request. During said request, an error may happen, in which case, an alert should show containing details. This error comes from a ViewModel and whenever it is set from nil to a string value, the alert should appear.
The "OK" button in the alert should dismiss it by setting the view model's error message back to nil.
Here is my implementation of the ViewModel.swift file:
import Foundation

@Observable
class ViewModel {
    var errorMessage: String?
    
    func doSomething() {
        self.errorMessage = "The image could not be downloaded"
    }
}

And here is my ContentView.swift:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Do something") {
                viewModel.doSomething()
            }
        }
        .alert(viewModel.errorMessage ?? "", isPresented: Binding(get: {
            viewModel.errorMessage != nil
        }, set: { value in
            viewModel.errorMessage = nil
        })) {
            Button("OK") {
                viewModel.errorMessage = nil
                // Here the view should be refreshed, then the "viewModel.errorMessage != nil" would hide the alert
            }
        }
    }
}

And the app entry point:
@main
struct Macos_SwiftUI_Alert_issueApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra("", systemImage: "square.fill") {
            ContentView()
                .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
    }
}

My issue:
I press the "Do something" button in the view (which causes the alert to appear), but when I press the "OK" button in the alert, the whole app view disappears, instead of just the alert disappearing. Also, when I open the menu bar app again, the alert is still present. After I press "OK" for a second time the whole view disappears again, and the third time I open my app, the alert finally goes. Has anyone seen this before or has a fix? Thanks in advance. Maybe I shouldn't even be using an alert to display an error message...?


I found a workaround to this problem a while later, that is, instead of using the SwiftUI .alert modifier, you can use the older AppKit NSAlert and make a function called showError to:

Make an NSAlert
Set the text in the message
(optional) Set the alert style
(optional) dismiss the menu window
Show the alert

Here is the code to fix the problem:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show error") {
                showError()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func showError() {
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = "An error occurred"
        alert.alertStyle = .warning
        dismiss()
        alert.runModal()
    }

}


@State should be a struct and try sheet(item:), e.g something like this:
struct Content {
    var errorMessage: String?
    
    mutating func doSomething() {
        self.errorMessage = "The image could not be downloaded"
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var content = Content()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Do something") {
                content.doSomething()
            }
        }
        .alert(item: $content.errorMessage) { errorMessage in
             Text(errorMessage)
             Button("OK") {
                content.errorMessage = nil
             }
        }


Thanks for the reply. I got this error message: Instance method 'alert(item:content:)' requires that 'String' conform to 'Identifiable'. Furthermore I need ViewModel to be an @Observable class because it is a view model!

That's wrong, in SwiftUI the View structs are the view model. It auto-generates the actual views on screen from the view model structs.

This should help with that error https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(item:content:)

Thank you very much for your help. I have been referring to Stewart Lynch's video to learn about the new Observation framework so would you say it is wrong?
Besides, I changed the alert for a popover instead and this seems to work fine.

Your class is "view model" thats wrong because the View struct hierarchy is the view model you shouldn't use classes for view data. @Observable is for model data, e.g. Stewart uses it for a User model. However, that's actually wrong for 2 reasons. There should be a class that holds the User model struct and is responsible for loading/saving it (and all the other model data). Also it can't be @State because that only works for structs. To use a class in SwiftUI it either needs to be @StateObject or be a singleton. The singleton is what Apple recommend since it also works with previews.

There should be a state property wrapper for @Observable out next month at WWDC, it'll likely be something like @StateObservable. However, don't use it for view models, you really need to learn the View struct and @State for dynamic data, let for readonly, @Binding var for read/write and computed var for transforming from model data to view data.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@DanielCrompton If it's helpful knowledge to have, I made a menu bar app same as yours on Ventura and what you're showing with the alert worked. It broke in my app for me when I updated to Sonoma. Now my entire window disappears when I interact with the alert too.

This is interesting, but I'm pleased to say I solved the issue below
